# Control wildcard expansion in sh command

Tags: bash, shell, wildcard

I have a program which executes shell functions using call like `sh -c "<command_string>"`. I can not change the way of calling these functions.

In this program I call different self written helper shell function, which are sourced into my environment. One of these looks like this. It unzips files with a given file pattern into a given directory.

```
function dwhUnzipFiles() {

    declare OPTIND=1
    while getopts "P:F:T:" opt; do
         case "$opt" in
         P) declare FILEPATTERN="$OPTARG" ;;
         F) declare FROMDIR="$OPTARG" ;;
         T) declare TODIR="$OPTARG" ;;
         *) echo "Unbekannte Option | Usage: dwhUnzipFiles -P <filepattern> -F <fromdir> -T <todir>"
         esac
    done
    shift $((OPTIND-1))

    for currentfile in "${FROMDIR}"/"${FILEPATTERN}" ; do 
        unzip -o "$currentfile" -d "${TODIR}"; 
    done

    # error handling
    # some more stuff

    return $?
}
```

For this function I use arguments with wildcards for the `FILEPATTERN` variable. The function gets called by my program like this:
`sh -c ". ~/dwh_env.sh && dwhUnzipFiles -P ${DWH_FILEPATTERN_MJF_WLTO}.xml.zip -F ${DWH_DIR_SRC_XML_CURR} -T ${DWH_DIR_SRC_XML_CURR}/workDir"` where `${DWH_FILEPATTERN_MJF_WLTO}` contains wildcards.

This works as intended. My confusion starts with another helper function, which is constructed in a similar way, but I'm not able to control the wildcard expansion correctly. It just deletes files in a directory depending on a given file pattern.

```
function dwhDeleteFiles() {

    declare retFlag=0

    declare OPTIND=1
    while getopts "D:P:" opt; do
         case "$opt" in
         D) declare DIRECTORY="$OPTARG" ;;
         P) declare FILEPATTERN="$OPTARG" ;;
         *) echo "Unbekannte Option | Usage: dwhDeleteFiles -D <Directory> -P <Filepattern>"
         esac
    done
    shift $((OPTIND-1))

    for currentfile in "${DIRECTORY}"/"${FILEPATTERN}" ; do 
        rm -fv "${currentfile}";
    done

    # error handling
    # some more stuff

    return $retFlag
}
```

This function is called like this:
`sh -c ". ~/dwh_env.sh && dwhDeleteFiles -P ${DWH_FILEPATTERN_MJF_WLTO}.xml -D ${DWH_DIR_SRC_XML_CURR}/workDir"` where again ${DWH_FILEPATTERN_MJF_WLTO} contains wildcards. When I call this function with my program it results in doing nothing. I tried to play around with adding `""` and `\"\"` to the arguments of my functions, but all what is happening is that instead of deleting all files in the given directory the function deletes only the first one in an alphanumerical order.

Can somebody explain to me, what is happening here? My idea is that the multiple passing of the variable, containing the wildcard, is not working. But how do I fix this and is it even possible in bash? And why is the `dwhUnzipFiles`function working and the `dwhDeleteFiles` is not?

Comment: `function dwhUnzipFiles() {` isn't valid in sh - that's bash-only syntax. (The standard way to declare a function is `dwhUnzipFiles() {` with no `function` keyword preceding). If this is called with `sh -c '...'`, then this code won't work reliably on platforms whose `sh` is provided by a shell other than `bash`.

Comment: Anyhow, your function's command line is broken out into an argument list before the function is started. You can't possibly change it from inside the function itself.

Comment: With respect to the playing around with literal quotes you've been doing -- see [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). Only syntactic quotes matter; literal quotes have no impact on glob expansions, except insofar as they're treated as part of the pattern to match.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this. I will have a look into the BashFAQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that `DWH_FILEPATTERN_MJF_WLTO` is `*`, and you have a bunch of *.xml files, then the command is

```
dwhDeleteFiles -P *.xml -D ${DWH_DIR_SRC_XML_CURR}/workDir
```

which expands to

```
dwhDeleteFiles -P bar.xml baz.xml foo.xml zap.xml -D ${DWH_DIR_SRC_XML_CURR}/workDir
```

(Note alphabetical order of xml files). But the `-P` option only takes **one** arg, `bar.xml` (the first) and the remaining are treated as file arguments.

Try setting `set -x` in your script to see this in action.

Comment: Thanks, this explains some of the behaviour I've seen while playing around.   I'll acccept this answer.